# Barra de Rolagem

Tags: delphi-7

Boa tarde Pessoal

Tenho uma grid no Delphi com 10 colunas, mas preciso habilitar uma barra de rolagem em apenas uma destas colunas. É possível?

No aguardo

Abraços

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] sua resposta e acrescentar qual o componente que está utilizando? Mesmo assim, não sei se é possível. Seria interessante comentar sobre o motivo de você querer fazer isso, talvez de outra maneira conseguimos resolver o problema do qual você está precisando ter uma coluna com barra de rolagem.

Comment: Quando você tem um dado muito extenso dentro de uma grid, o que eu costumo fazer é deixar com que a célula seja compactada, e adicionar um evento de clique pra que exiba uma pequena modal com o conteúdo completo.

Comment: Muito bom @DH. também já fiz algo assim :)